Flutter app not building on iOS simulator
I'm trying to start a Flutter project I have gotten on a iOS Simulator and the problem is I can't. On another Mac, my friend was able to start it but I have been running in circles... I have tried:
**

Product > Clean Build Folder
deleted Pod folder and PodFile.lock and pod repo update - pod install
Erase all content and settings in the iOS Simulator
flutter clean, flutter pub get
inside the podfile :config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15.0' // or to any target for that matter
Podfile:

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '15.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  # pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.3.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
      xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
      IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        #'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
        # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
        # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
        # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
      ]
      end
    end

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
      #config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] << '-D BYPASS_PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS'
      #config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] << '-D BYPASS_PERMISSION_IOSADDTOPHOTOLIBRARY'
      #config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] << '-D BYPASS_PERMISSION_IOSCHANGEPHOTOLIBRARY'
      end
  end
end

I have tried this in different orders and still no use. The errors (I haven't put them all since they are huge) are:
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:559C4BFF-EDD7-47C0-BBF0-23EFA0F09B49, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:559C4BFF-EDD7-47C0-BBF0-23EFA0F09B49, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/zy/s6zpmk8x1sz8rh2r5f6cf0040000gn/T/flutter_tools.LUGgCm/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirp82spW/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
    ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
    ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
    ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
    /Users/user/Downloads/app-flavors/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:34:29: warning: 'alert' was deprecated in iOS 14.0
            completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
                                ^
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gbukoovcjoxwzreoddwxmohrumea/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-dev-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-486182A2307E10650A730B9F.sh: line 5: flutterfire: command not found
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/user/Downloads/app-flavors/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.5.99. (in target 'wakelock_plus-thermal' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/user/Downloads/app-flavors/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.5.99. (in target 'permission_handler_apple-permission_handler_apple_privacy' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/user/Downloads/app-flavors/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.5.99. (in target 'nanopb-nanopb_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/user/Downloads/app-flavors/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.5.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/user/Downloads/app-flavors/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library-leveldb_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/user/Downloads/app-flavors/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.5.99. (in target 'flutter_local_notifications-flutter_local_notifications_privacy' from project 'Pods')

etc...


I'm not sure what is the problem... Can the problem be the cocoapods or the PATHs ~/.zshrc files?
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:/user/local/opt/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.22.2/flutter/bin:$PATH"

in the  My flutter doctor -v is without issues. Any form of help is greatly needed and appreciated.

I was facing a similar error and couldn't understand what was wrong. I git cloned my repository to another folder and it worked. Then I found that my parent directory name has space in between. Maybe that is in your case too...

I think main issue is this string from log:
line 5: flutterfire: command not found

Looks like your project uses firebase, which requires some additional configuration of your development environment. I recommend you to follow these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios
This particular issue with flutterfire can be resolved with this step
Also, make sure that dart packages are in your path, here is documentation for this

Open your project in Xcode.
Check your Flutter SDK path and project path


FLUTTER_ROOT -> /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.22.2/flutter, FLUTTER_TARGET -> Users/user/Downloads/app-flavors/lib/main.dart.. seems its ok

Same in All debug, Profile and release?

yes.. the agony continues.. :) thanks for the help tho

my friend started the project on the same type of Mac without setting up anyhting, it just built on the first try lol

I got the same error a few months ago, and I am trying to remove and reinstall Cocoapods and it works.
From the error message, Have you been using any 3rd party packages?
You can try to set the Deployment target for your Pods references with the following command:
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
  end
 end
end

or remove the value:
Code Block 
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
  end
 end
end

Hopely this can help you to fix the issue :)
